# JavaScript - reverse an array in a specific way

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm doing an algorithm course and here is the instructor's answer about how to reverse an array without using reverse js method:

```
function solution(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
    var tempVar = arr[i]
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i]
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = tempVar
  }

  return arr
}
```

I did understand everything, EXCEPT this detail:

```
arr.length/2
```

In this line below:

```
 for(var i=0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
```

what does it mean? What its purpose?

Comment: It's the limit for when the `for` loop stops. Are you familiar with `for` loops or is it just this algorithm which is not clear?

Comment: I'm familiar with loops.I didn't understand the purpose to divide for 2 the array length to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse a string, you have to swap characters of first half of the string with the last half.

```
let str = 'abcde';
```

You have to swap `a` with `e`, `b` with `d`.

`ab` is the first half of the string. So simply run loop over the first half of the string and swap `i`th character with `arr.length - 1 - i`th character as below

```
var tempVar = arr[i]
arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i]
arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = tempVar
```

Comment: If as you say `For reverse a string, you have to swap first half of the string with the last half` then for  string `abcdef` your result will be `cdeabc` - which is not reversed string.

Comment: New edition which is `For reverse a string, you have to swap characters of half of the string with the last half` - also is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm start with first and last element and swap them. Next it take the second element from the begin and from the end and swap them. And etc it swap all the elements with same distance from center.

So algorithm go to the center of array from both sides. And it need only half of length of array from both side to proceed. So that statement `arr.length/2` actually the expression which is a half of length.

Which is used as limit of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm swaps two elements that are on equal distance from both ends of the array. The number of operations needed is `number_of_operations = number_of_elements / number_elements_operated_on` and since it's doing two elements at once, that's `number_of_elements / 2`. And hence the reason to use `arr.length / 2` as the limit of the `for` loop. Here is a representation of what happens.

Given an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` then `array.length` is `6` and the following operations are performed:

```
//loop i = 0, 0 < 3 == true, execute
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
 ^--------------^      ^--------------^

//loop i = 1, 1 < 3 == true, execute
[6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1] -> [6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1]
    ^--------^            ^--------^


//loop i = 2, 2 < 3 == true, execute
[6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1] -> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
       ^--^                  ^--^

//i = 3, 3 < 3 == false, loop stops
```

This works perfectly fine with odd number of elements, since there is going to just be one element in middle when you get to it.

Given an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` then `array.length` is `5` and the following operations are performed:

```
//loop i = 0, 0 < 2.5 == true, execute
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
 ^-----------^      ^-----------^

//loop i = 1, 1 < 2.5 == true, execute
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1] -> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    ^-----^            ^-----^


//loop i = 2, 2 < 2.5 == true, execute
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1] -> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
       ^                  ^

//i = 3, 3 < 2.5 == false, loop stops
```